# Family of norms ordered by a peculiar relation

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a vector space together with a family $\left( \left \Vert \cdot \right \Vert_k \right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of norms.
For what I am working on, I have proved that I need a kind of ordering property on the norms such that $\forall k,l \in \mathbb{N} \; \forall x \in X :$

\begin{equation}
k \le l \implies B^k_{\left \Vert x \right \Vert_k} \left( 0 \right) \subseteq B^l_{\left \Vert x \right \Vert_l} \left( 0 \right)
\end{equation}

where $B^k_r \left( 0 \right)$ denotes the open ball of radius $r$ in the $\left \Vert \cdot \right \Vert_k$ norm around $0$.

I have never seen such a property before and so I wonder whether such families of norms have been studied before and if so what name is given to them and perhaps what alternative characterizations might exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given inclusion is equivalent to $\|z\|_k\le\|x\|_k\implies\|z\|_l\le\|x\|_l$ for all $x,z$.

By symmetry this implies $\|z\|_k=\|x\|_k\implies \|z\|_l=\|x\|_l$.

Hence $B^k_r=\alpha B^l_r$, since suppose $\|x\|_l/\|x\|_k=\alpha$ for some fixed $x$. Then for any other $y$ such that $\|y\|_k=r$, $\|y\|_k=\|\frac{rx}{\|x\|_k}\|_k$ implies $\|y\|_l=r\|x\|_l/\|x\|_k=r\alpha$.

So the  norms are equal in the sense that $\|x\|_k=f(k)\|x\|_1$.